# Start function inside overriden Asynctask method of the same class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have AsyncTask class and I call it in my main class. I need to override the onPostExecute function and call inside ftpDisconnect(). But it does not work properly.

```
TempClass dj = new TempClass(serialnum) {

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        pr_bar.setProgress(values[0]);
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //dj.ftpDisconnect(); //need to make this happen
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
};

dj.execute();
```

My TempClass:

```
public class TempClass extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    public TempClass(String serialnum) {
    this.serialnum = serialnum;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //do stuff
        return null;
    }

    public boolean ftpDisconnect() {

        try {       
            mFTPClient.disconnect();            
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error? can u post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access that instance of `dj` without making it final. You should be able to call `ftpDisconnect` from inside the class:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    ftpDisconnect();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```